# Cannot install R on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, r

I have just migrated from windows, successfully installed Ubuntu 18.04, and was trying to install R. However, I get the following error after following steps descrbed [here](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/README.html).

```
$ sudo apt-get install r-base-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-dev : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.5.2-1bionic) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: build-essential but it is not installable
              Depends: gcc but it is not installable
              Depends: g++ but it is not installable
              Depends: gfortran but it is not installable
              Depends: libblas-dev but it is not installable or
                       libatlas-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: liblapack-dev but it is not installable or
                       libatlas-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libncurses5-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: libreadline-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: libjpeg-dev but it is not installable
              Depends: libpcre3-dev but it is not installable


         Depends: libpng-dev but it is not installable
          Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not installable
          Depends: libbz2-dev but it is not installable
          Depends: liblzma-dev but it is not installable
          Depends: libicu-dev but it is not installable
```

`E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to install the wrong package - `r-base-dev` doesn't contain R tools for themselves, it contains the sources so you can compile them yourself. You don't need it to use R.

To install R interpreter you should install the package `r-base`, using a command like this:

```
sudo apt install r-base
```

If you don't need the latest R tools (i.e. released less than 6 months ago), you can safely install R from the default Ubuntu repositories, so APT can take care of all the required packages.

You just need to make sure to enable the `universe` repository from "Software & Updates" app.

I suggest you to disable previously enabled CRAN R repositories. You can do it from "Software & Updates" app.